# How to convert a 2D binary object in to a Dictonary<string, object> in C# using Binary Formatter

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, redis, binaryformatter, binary-deserialization

I want to convert an objeect of byte[][] type to Dictonary.

It always give an error **"End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed."**

Please help me .

```
 public static object ByteToObjectArray(byte[][] ms)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        mStream.Write(ms, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        mStream.Position = 0;
        return formatter.Deserialize(mStream) as object;

    }
```

Comment: `var d = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ms.ToString());` I don't know what you are trying to do, but this line is sooo much wrong and without meaning...

Comment: Now, count until 10 and then try to explain how a `byte[][]`, a `Dictionary<string, object>`, an `Encoding.ASCII` and a `BinaryFormatter` should be used together to create a ??? (unclear what)

Comment: my mistake. i have changed the code.

Comment: The code doesn't explain anything. What is in that array of buffers and what logic would convert any of them to a Dictionary of .... what? Why use a `BinaryFormatter` at all?

Comment: Before writing a deserializer, show us how the deserializer should work... You have a `Dictionary<string, object>`... From here how should you arrive to a `byte[][]`? Where are the keys? Where are the values?

Comment: @xanatos , Hi, am using redis cache. In that , HgetAll function returns the output as Byte[][] . The out is basically a list of object. So, now to use it , i have to convert it into dictionary type to make use of it. I am able to do conversion from byte[] to object. But unable to do with byte[][] . If you have any idea or an approach please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The `HGETALL` should return the data as

```
key1
data1
key2
data2
...
```

So interleaved... Now... Supposing the `key` is in UTF8:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ByteToObjectArray(byte[][] bytes)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
    {
        string key = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes[i]);
        // Alternatively
        //string key = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes[i]);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes[i + 1]))
        {
            object obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);

            dict.Add(key, obj);
        }
    }

    return dict;
}
```